# sqoop import - control M character

Tags: special-characters, sqoop

All,

Working on importing data from DB2 using sqoop import, it worked fine for the most part except one table, which seemed to have some special characters ( control-M = ^M ) in contents, hence while sqooping, these characters are treated as newline and hence everything after it will be on the next line in the imported files, which will affect all the records after one bad record.

I am unable to guess how to fix the imports? is there any eazy way?

Comment: Can you add your Sqoop import command ?

Answer (score 0):

As possible solution you can remove special characters in the import query:

```
replace(replace(source_db_column,chr(13),''),chr(10), '') as source_db_column
```

In this case it will be done by source database before sqoop will fetch data.

Another option is to use `--hive-drop-import-delims` parameter to the `sqoop import` command along with `--map-column-java` option to specify that column is of type String:

```
sqoop import
...
--hive-drop-import-delims 
--map-column-java your_column=String
```

And one more option is to use  `--hive-delims-replacement "some_character"` again with `--map-column-java your_column=String` to replace special characters (`\n , \t , and \01`) with some other character.